# Can I use a non-defining and defining clause for the same noun?

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-clauses, clauses, reduced-relative-clauses

I'm curious if I can use a non-defining and defining clause/phrase in a row for the same noun in a sentence.

For instance,

1. **I sold the ring, an expensive one, that I bought a few years ago.** (I intend to use "that" here as a defining clause and "an expensive one" as a phrase for more detail)
2. **I sold the ring, which is an expensive one, that I bought a few years ago.** ("which is an expensive one" is for detail, "that" is for definition.)

I know I can combine them shortening the sentence, however what about this kind of usage?